# Pandas Series: Decrement DateTime by 100 Years

Tags: pandas, datetime, date-conversion

I have a pandas series as follows...

```
0  2039-03-16 
1  2056-01-21 
2  2051-11-18 
3  2064-03-05 
4  2048-06-05

Name: BIRTH, dtype: datetime64
```

It was created from string data as follows

```
s = data['BIRTH']
s = pd.to_datetime(s)
s
```

I want to convert all dates after year 2040 to 1940

I can do this for a single record as follows

```
s.iloc[0].replace(year=d.year-100)
```

but I really want to just run it over the whole series. I can't work it out. Help!??

PS - I know there's ways outside of pandas using Python's DT module but I'd like to learn how to do this within Pandas please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html#pandas-tseries-offsets-dateoffset) is the obvious choice here:

```
df['date'] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=100)

0   1939-03-16
1   1956-01-21
2   1951-11-18
3   1964-03-05
4   1948-06-05
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Assign it back:

```
df['date'] -= pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=100)
df
        date
0 1939-03-16
1 1956-01-21
2 1951-11-18
3 1964-03-05
4 1948-06-05
```

We have the `offsets` module to deal with non-fixed frequencies, it comes in handy in situations like these.

---

To fix your code, you'd have wanted to apply `datetime.replace` rowwise using `apply` (not recommended):

```
df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(year=x.year-100))

0   1939-03-16
1   1956-01-21
2   1951-11-18
3   1964-03-05
4   1948-06-05
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or using a list comprehension,

```
df.assign(date=[x.replace(year=x.year-100) for x in df['date']])

        date
0 1939-03-16
1 1956-01-21
2 1951-11-18
3 1964-03-05
4 1948-06-05
```

Neither of these handle NaT entries very well.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Actually I was wanting to decrement the dates conditionally on the series. Here's the code in case it helps anyone...  s[s.dt.year > 2000 ] -= pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=100)

Comment: @AxleMax the DateOffset approach is a lot more flexible. Thanks for the update.

Comment: actually I can't get it to work conditionally on the DF (only on a series). I basically need this "df['date'] -= pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=100)" but only when "df['date'].dt.year > 1950". Any advice please?

Comment: @AxleMax Try `df['date'] = np.where(df['date'].dt.year > 1950, df['date'] - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=100), df['date'])`

Comment: Nailed it!! Thank you again